# Sorting an original HTTP request from the subsequent, automatic related requests

Tags: http, web

I want to look at a pcap file in python and sort out HTTP requests.  But, I only want the original request (eg. http://www.site.com/index.html), and not the several requests that are subsequent and automatic, such as embedded content, advertising, etc.  I want my script to only return the one, original request that the user himself initiated.

How can I differentiate programatically between the user initiated request, and subsequent requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP requests have no links to each other (the `Referer` header can be sent in user-initiated requests, so that is not good enough), and nothing to indicate whether a given request is manual or automated.  The only option is to actually parse the content of the first response, extract all of the possible automated URLs from it (scripts, images, etc), then check subsequent requests to see if they are for those URLs, parse those responses for more URLs, and so on.